# OpenTK GenFramebuffers error

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I am trying to use GenFramebuffers function from OpenTK. In native OpenGL this function takes a number of framebuffer names to generate and a pointer to int where the names will be stored. But OpenTK variant takes a number of names to generate and **a single** out Int32 parameter.

Here's the source code of the function from OpenTK:

```
    public static void GenFramebuffers(Int32 n, out Int32 framebuffers)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (Int32* framebuffers_ptr = &framebuffers)
            {
                Delegates.glGenFramebuffers((Int32)n, (UInt32*)framebuffers_ptr);
                framebuffers = *framebuffers_ptr;
            }
        }
    }
```

As far as I can see it will overwrite memory if anything else than 1 is specified as n. To make sure, I actually tried it with n=2, and indeed it wrote the Int32 that I passed as out parameter plus one Int32 that happened to be in memory after it.

This is not the only affected function in OpenTK, all genXXX functions are like that.

Am I going crazy here or is OpenTK seriously broken?

Answer (score 1):

I think that is internal function. OpenTK has this function in GL class to generate single framebuffer:

```
    public static int GenFramebuffer()
    {
        int id;
        GenFramebuffers(1, out id);
        return id;
    }
```

For array type argument OpenTK has these functions:

```
void GenFramebuffers(Int32 n, [OutAttribute] Int32[] framebuffers)
unsafe void GenFramebuffers(Int32 n, [OutAttribute] Int32* framebuffers)
```

But I believe you can also use function you mention in this way:

```
int[] arr = new int[15];
GenFramebuffers(10, out arr[5]); // will fill 10 starting with index 5
```

Comment: If it's internal it should not be public and I shouldn't be allowed to call it.

Comment: It's a public API, but it's your responsibility to use it correctly. You can pick between the array overload (for multiple values), the out overload (for a single return value, where you don't want to allocate a 1-element array) and the unsafe pointer overload (useful for non-GC data allocations.)